# How do I create a 2D-array without any loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this question whereby I need to set up an array without any loops.

I have no idea as to where to start. I was thinking of creating the array with the desired length first and then put the elements in it. However, I don't think that'll work because it'll mean that I have to hardcode the array with the desired length?

Comment: if you don't want to use loops, you will have to hardcode the lengths of the 2D array. But the bigger question is: why you don't want to use for-loops? If you explain this or give some context we may be able to help find a solution

Comment: If you mean absolutely no loops even from native code i think the only way would be through recursion, but that is still fundamentally a loop

Comment: if you put elements in, you can use `Array.push` to create the array without any loops. You need loop to read input anyway.

Comment: It was specified that I can't use loops for this question so :').

Comment: [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9,0,1], ...]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of creating an array that contains 3 empty arrays with `.fill()` and `.map()`

```
let arr = new Array(3).fill().map(()=>new Array())
```

`.fill()` is needed so that you can have values to map, `.map()` creates new arrays. Note that calling something like `.fill(new Array())` won't work well, because it will populate it with references to the same array.